# Appending fields in a file to another one based on ID

Tags: matlab, awk

Basically, I need a script that can solve the problem in very short time. I have two files:

$ head -n 6 fcu.tsv

```
NM576455     0.324009324     0.578896174     2577
NM539570     0.204545455     0.607877092     2247
NM337132     0.288973384     0.673636364     792
NM374379     0.308300395     0.42            762
NM373443     0.263043478     0.547132867     1383
NM371839     0.298210736     0.492857143     1512
```

$ head -n 6 mart.tsv

```
NM539570 ILMN_2199362    15      58.52   protein_coding
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding molecular_function      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding molecular_function      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_type1
```

We need to append the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th fields of fcu.tsv to mart.tsv for each NM id in very short time.

$ head out.tsv

```
NM539570 ILMN_2199362    15      58.52   protein_coding  0.204545455     0.607877092     2247
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_2 0.324009324   0.578896174     2577
    NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding molecular_function      SAM_2 0.324009324   0.578896174     2577
    NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_2 0.324009324   0.578896174     2577
    NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding molecular_function      SAM_2 0.324009324   0.578896174     2577
    NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_type1 0.324009324   0.578896174     2577
```

This is what I did in matlab (I prefer that solution fix the bad codes here to make it faster rather than writing a new one)

```
fr1 = fopen('fcu.tsv', 'r');
fr2 = fopen('mart.tsv', 'r');

fw = fopen('out.tsv', 'w');

while feof(fr1) == 0
   line = fgetl(fr1);
   scan = textscan(line, '%s%f%f%d');

   frewind(fr2);

    while feof(fr2) == 0
        line2 = fgetl(fr2);
        scan2 = textscan(line2, '%s%s%s%f%s%s%s%s');

            if scan{1}{1} == scan2{1}{1} 

                fprintf(fw, '%s\t%f\t%f\t%d\n', line2, scan{2}, scan{3}, scan{4});

            end

    end

end
```

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a command-line centric solution, works on any system supporting `coreutils`, apologies if it is not applicable in your case.

If `mart.tsv` was padded properly, as in:

```
NM539570 ILMN_2199362    15      58.52   protein_coding  NA      NA                 NA                      NA
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component NA                      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding            molecular_function      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component NA                      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding            molecular_function      SAM_2
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component NA                      SAM_type1
```

The solution could be a simple `join` (see `info join`):

```
$ join <(sort mart.tsv) <(sort fcu.tsv) | column -t
NM539570  ILMN_2199362  15  58.52  protein_coding  NA       NA                  NA                  NA         0.204545455  0.607877092  2247
NM576455  ILMN_1709067  1   65.74  protein_coding  nucleus  cellular_component  NA                  SAM_2      0.324009324  0.578896174  2577
NM576455  ILMN_1709067  1   65.74  protein_coding  protein  binding             molecular_function  SAM_2      0.324009324  0.578896174  2577
NM576455  ILMN_2195138  1   65.74  protein_coding  nucleus  cellular_component  NA                  SAM_2      0.324009324  0.578896174  2577
NM576455  ILMN_2195138  1   65.74  protein_coding  nucleus  cellular_component  NA                  SAM_type1  0.324009324  0.578896174  2577
NM576455  ILMN_2195138  1   65.74  protein_coding  protein  binding             molecular_function  SAM_2      0.324009324  0.578896174  2577
```

`column` comes from the `bsdmainutils` package.

Comment: Everything is ok but I have two questions: 
1) How you padded the mart.tsv (add NA in any empty field) ?
2) Why you use column ? The results looks so wired with many spaces between fields I did it without column and the results looks better

Comment: 1) I did it manually, how you go about it depends on where the results come from. 2) Just for formatting, if the result is going into a program it is superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `awk`. For case `FNR == NR` it reads first input file of arguments (`fcu.tsv`) and saves in a hash with first field as the key and the rest of fields joined with `\t` as values. For `FNR < NR` reads `mart.tsv` and if first field matches the key of the hash, join its value at the end of the line, otherwise print original line.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
}

FNR == NR {
    for ( i = 2; i <= NF; i++ ) { 
        line = (line ? line OFS : "") $i
    }   
    fcu[ $1 ] = line 
    line = ""
    next
}

FNR < NR {
    if ( $1 in fcu ) { 
        print $0 OFS fcu[ $1 ]
    }   
    else {
        print $0
    }   
}
```

Run it like:

```
awk -f script.awk fcu.tsv mart.tsv
```

With following output:

```
NM539570 ILMN_2199362    15      58.52   protein_coding 0.204545455     0.607877092     2247
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_2  0.324009324     0.578896174     2577
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding molecular_function      SAM_2  0.324009324     0.578896174     2577
NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_2  0.324009324     0.578896174     2577
NM576455 ILMN_1709067    1       65.74   protein_coding  protein binding molecular_function      SAM_2  0.324009324     0.578896174     2577
NM576455 ILMN_2195138    1       65.74   protein_coding  nucleus cellular_component      SAM_type1      0.324009324     0.578896174     2577
```